# JQuery Ajax: Random order of dynamic div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of images that I need to render on page. The image is coming from a third party API. I get the list and using for loop I display the image.

```
var count = imageIds.length;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
GetImage(imageIds[i]);
}

function GetImage(imageId){
//Ajax request here. Returns string "data" for image.
//Once the request finishes, I update the div's content like:
_targetDiv.append('<img class="thumb" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data + '"/>';
}
```

The problem is the images are not rendering in order. The above code arranges the image in any order based on the finished request. I need to render image 1, then image 2, then image 3 and so on...

What's the fix?

Comment: Need to show more code context regarding the ajax

Comment: Check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of request promises  and use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to process the response data in the same order as the original data

```js
var imageIds = [1,2,3,4,5];

var promiseArray = imageIds.map(getImage);

$.when.apply(null, promiseArray).then(function(){
   // array of data received for each request, in same order as original data array
   var array = [].slice.call(arguments);

   array.forEach(function(item){
      $('body').append('<p> Item #' + item.id +'</p>')
   })
}).fail(function(){
   // one or more of the requests failed...handle error 
});

function getImage(imageId){ 
   var url ='https://simple-express-cors-endpoint-be970g7kgnc3.runkit.sh';
   // return the request promise
   return $.post(url, {id: imageId}).then(function(data){
       console.log('Request for #'+imageId+' completed');
       // resolve with response data
       return data;
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to preserve the ordering of Requests and Responses.

1. Render all the images finally after all of them have been loaded

   ```
   var count = imageIds.length;
   var responses = [];
   var completedCount = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       GetImage(imageIds[i], i);
   }

   function GetImage(imageId, requestIndex){
       // Ajax query goes here
       // Push the response and the requestIndex into our responses Array
       responses.push({ index: requestIndex, data: data });
       completedCount = completedCount + 1;
       // Render the images only after all responses have been obtained
       if(completedCount === count) {
           renderAllImages();
       }
   }

   function renderAllImages() {
       // Sort responses based on the request Index so that we preserve ordering
       responses.sort(function(a, b) {
           var keyA = a.requestIndex,
           var keyB = b.requestIndex;
           // Compare the 2 dates
           if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
           if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
           return 0;
       });

       // Render all images finally after sorted
       for(var i=0; i<responses.length; i++) {
           _targetDiv.append('<img class="thumb" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + responses[i].data + '"/>';

       }
   }
   ```
2. Render the images as they load, preserving the order in which the requests were sent

   ```
   var count = imageIds.length;
   var responses = [];
   var completedCount = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       GetImage(imageIds[i], i);
   }

   function GetImage(imageId, requestIndex){
       // Ajax query goes here
       // Push the response and the requestIndex into our responses Array
       responses.push({ index: requestIndex, data: data });
       completedCount = completedCount + 1;
       // Render all the images we have loaded so far after each response
       renderAllImages();
   }

   function renderAllImages() {
       // Sort responses based on the request Index so that we preserve ordering
       responses.sort(function(a, b) {
           var keyA = a.requestIndex,
           var keyB = b.requestIndex;
           // Compare the 2 dates
           if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
           if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
           return 0;
       });

       // Render all images finally after sorted
       for(var i=0; i<responses.length; i++) {
           _targetDiv.append('<img class="thumb" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + responses[i].data + '"/>';

       }
   }
   ```